# How to create copy(workspace) of depot on local machine in P4?

Tags: mercurial, tags, clone, perforce

What is equivalent of `hg clone` command of mercurial in perforce?

*or*

How to create a workspace using P4 command line commands?

I tried:

```
p4 sync //depot/my_depot/... //workspace/...
```

msg:

```
//depot/my_depot/... - must refer to client 'desk24'.
//workspace/... - must refer to client 'desk24'.
```

Can we tag in perforce, just like we do `hg tag` in mercurial?

Comment: Have you seen this doc? http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PerforceConcepts Check out the part that has commands in a corresponding table 'Perforce-to-Mercurial Cheat sheet'

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The 'p4 tag' command is equivalent to 'hg tag'. For more details about tagging in Perforce see the following:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_tag.html

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.labels.html

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Static-and-Automatic-Label-Performance-Considerations

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Saving-the-Contents-of-a-Label

Reference:
[Perforce-to-Mercurial Cheat sheet](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PerforceConcepts)

Answer (score 1):

To create a client workspace and populate it with the head revisions from the depot:

```
p4 client
p4 sync
```

To clone a local repository (i.e. copy all revisions from the depot into your own local depot with its own local workspace):

```
p4 clone -p P4PORT //depot/my_depot/...
```